# How to read an expression that is ambiguous?

Tags: functions, notation, parsing

(1) How should I parenthesize $\log n \log \log n$?  Also: (2) What general rule/rationale is used to do this parenthesization?

To elaborate; I see why $\log\log n$ is unambiguous, but $\log n \log ...$ could mean at least 2 different things:

> $\log(n\log(...))$

... or:

> $\log(n)*\log(...)$

How do I best decide which one the author intended?

Comment: You're right it's ambiguous, but $\log(n)\cdot \log(\log(n))$ is always what is meant.

Comment: Wow, that was crazy fast.  Why don't you post that as an answer so I can upvote you for it?

Comment: Similar to reading $\cos x \sin y$ as $\cos(x)\times\sin(y)$ instead of $\cos (x \sin (y))$ it is *generally* safe to interpret such constructs as products rather than convolutions.  It is what is *usually* meant.

Comment: Because without seeing the expression in context, I'm not certain I am correct.

Comment: Since $\log (n\log\log n) = \log n + \log\log\log n$, it is better to assume the one that *cannot* be written another way. Especially if this is a "big-O" approximation, since $O(\log n + \log\log\log n) = O(\log n)$.

Comment: For context, I took the subexpression from the end of this section on the computation of the Factorial function:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Computation so it is in the context of "big-O".  Thanks for the insight @ThomasAndrews!